# Store `.Range` object entirely in memory?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to store `.Range` object entirely in memory?

I want to store ranges as dictionary values and then be able to unpack the ranges somewhere else. But before unpacking, the original ranges will be modified.

This is the code I have for storing the ranges in dictionary:

```
Sub range_to_dict()

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim d As New scripting.Dictionary
Dim rng As Range
Dim rw As Range
Dim paste_loc As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:B13")
Set paste_loc = rng.Offset(rng.Rows.Count + 2, 0).Resize(1, 1)

For Each rw In rng.Rows
    d.Add (rw.Cells(1).Value), rw
Next rw

For Each k In d.Keys
    d(k).Copy
    paste_loc.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Set paste_loc = paste_loc.Offset(1, 0)
Next k

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

It will do the job only if I don't modify the ranges between creating the dict and unpacking, because while unpacking the VBA still reads the ranges from sheet, not from memory (dictionary):

```
Sub range_to_dict()

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim d As New scripting.Dictionary
Dim rng As Range
Dim rw As Range
Dim paste_loc As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:B13")
Set paste_loc = rng.Offset(rng.Rows.Count + 2, 0).Resize(1, 1)

For Each rw In rng.Rows
    d.Add (rw.Cells(1).Value), rw
Next rw

'modify (clear)
For Each rw In rng.Rows
    rw.Clear
Next rw

'now this will paste only empty fields
For Each k In d.Keys
    d(k).Copy
    paste_loc.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Set paste_loc = paste_loc.Offset(1, 0)
Next k

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I could achieve what I want through storing each range cells value in an array or collection, and then unpack them, but is there a less wordy way?

Comment: A `Range` object is nothing more than a "view window" to a range of cells on a sheet. You cannot have a `Range` that is disconnected from cells and has its own `Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to store a `Range` in a variable (memory). It is always just a reference to the original range that is stored in the variable.

But you can read the *values* of the range into an array:

```
Dim MyArr As Variant
MyArr = Range("A1:A10").Value
```

If you now modify your range A1:A10 the array will still contain the old values.

And of course you can write them back into cells

```
Range("A1:A10").Value = MyArr
```

note that when writing back, the range must be the same size as the array. Otherwise some values will be missing.

Comment: Thanks. By "not possible" do you mean that such feature is just not implemented in VBA?

Comment: @barciewicz Yes, there is no possibility in VBA to have a range object that is not connected to cells in a worksheet. `Range("A1:A10")` is only a reference that is pointing to the actual range in the worksheet, nothing more. There is no way to have a "virtual" range that is disconnected from a worksheet.

Comment: @barciewicz This feature is not implemented in Excel, not in VBA (you can use the Excel object model from any language that supports COM). I'm pretty certain it will never be implemented either.