# How much memory is allocated for a Range variable in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, memory-management

What is better in Excel VBA in terms of less memory allocation, better memory management and less memory usage:

(1) to use a static variable for the Range.Value which I have to update every time on worksheet change,

```
Dim myValue as Integer: myValue = Range("XYZ").Value: Debug.Print myValue
```

(2) or pointer to the Range object?

```
Dim myValue as Range: Set myValue = Range("XYZ"): Debug.Print myValue.Value
```

Comment: Those would achieve different things, so I don't really understand the question.

Comment: A VBA Integer variable takes 4 bytes of memory.  What I really care now is how much raw memory it would take to use "Dim myValue as Range"?

Comment: An object reference is 4 bytes in VBA. Why does it matter?

Comment: In terms of performance, I'm not going to debate whether 4 bytes or 4 bytes is better but why would you care about one line of code getting/displaying a value? If there's a bigger range, then you're better off getting the entire range's value in an array in one go rather than going cell by cell. If it's just for this one cell's value, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks guys, but please write your answers as an answer, not comments only.

The written above, (1) and (2) are example rows of what I'm looking for.  Imagine a code with many large Named Ranges.  I can use the Named Range as object reference. 
 It much improves performance than reading the cell values in variables.  However, I was not sure how large the Range object could be.  Now, I understood that it is a pointer to location on a sheet, it takes 4 bytes, and it is NOT a copy of all the cell values in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly: You shouldn't care about it. Use whatever is more convenient for you.

Some remarks:

- Local variables are always thrown away anyhow when a routine ends, so even if one of those variables would consume more memory, it doesn't matter.
- Object variables are references (kind of pointer) and consume only the memory that is needed to that reference.
- I highly doubt that there is any difference in speed for both attempts, and even if there is one, you can measure it only when you repeat the code a million times or so.
- Your integer variable is not static. A static variable is a local variable that survives the end of a subroutine. It is used only very seldom, and in your case it makes no sense to have it static.
- Even with a large amount of data, you usually shouldn't care about memory consumption. On every modern computer, using some MByte of memory temporarily doesn't matter at all. If you have to deal with a lot of data, read it into an Array before you process it - that speeds up execution time dramatically.
- In VBA, forget about Integer and always use Long.

Comment: Yep, tested it with 100 000 cycles, the reference "Range"-variant takes 2.0 seconds and is 0.5 seconds quicker than the variable-variant.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to use `Debug.Print myValue.Value` if it was bigger however. You'd already get a type mismatch if you have more than one cell in the XYZ-range. Named ranges are used for easy access/making it more understandable what you're using.

Not sure where you got the 4 bytes for an Integer from, see [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) (2 bytes for Integer, 4 for Long) and like FunThomas said, back in ye-olde-time we had to distinguish Integer from Long because our systems were older. Now just use Long instead of Integer and only distinguish if it's *really* necessary. Long is more flexible due to its size-difference (and less error-prone with the rows exceeding the Integer's capacity).

```
Dim myValue as Range: Set myValue = Range("XYZ"): Debug.Print myValue.Value
```

Would be more useful than not setting your range first if you need to use it more than once. Declaring a variable to use it only once is most of the time unnecessary apart from having cleaner looking code.

Bigger range-manipulations will be easier in an array (which would take the Variant-type) because you *will* have a better performance having less interaction between Excel and VBA. See [this answer from Peh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53316488/19353309) for an example.

Comment: My bad, I was looking at the VB language reference here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/ which curiously appears to be different from VBA.

Comment: There are similarities between them but it's better to always check, yeah :)